# Domain Forwarding not Working with PHP Header Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, dns, subdomain, forwarding

I have a domain, let's call it **example.com**. On that domain I have a subdomain set up, let's call that **test.example.com**. That **test.example.com** is set up to Forward to another website entirely, **different.com**.

I also another subdomain on **example.com** called **redirect.example.com**. On it is a simple PHP file that reads the BASENAME of a URL checks a DB for certain criteria and based on the matching record does a header() redirect to the URL in the db for that record.

In Google Chrome & Firefox the following scenario works fine, but with Safari & Internet Explorer this happens...

> 1. Enter "redirect.example.com/123456"
> 2. "redirect.example" php file reads basename of 123456 and checks against DB
> 3. "redirect.example" php file header() redirects to "test.example.com"
> 4. Safari replaces "test.example.com" in address bar with localhost/example.com
> 5. IE loads nothing and says "This page can't be displayed"

I imagine this may seem a bit convoluted and strange, but regardless lol I'm not sure why Safari is handling it different than the other browsers.

Any ideas/thoughts? I don't think it is relevant to the problem but here is a snippet that handles the redirect.

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$redirect = $row['link'];
$default = "https://google.com";
if ($row['status'] == 0) {
    header( 'Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit();
}
else {
    header( 'Location: ' . $default);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: you need to include the protocol for a full url in your header, also, make sure you call exit or die. `header("Location: http://somewhere.com"); exit;`

Comment: also, show the code rather than walking us through every step.

Comment: @pamblamamammaaam I didn't think it was a "code" issue. More of a process of the forwarding and how the browsers may handle them.

Comment: it's a always a "code" issue if you're posting on so. if it's not a code issue it belongs on a different stackexchange site. SO is for "code" issues.

Comment: can't argue you with that. thought i was on se. first time for everything.

Comment: so is a se site :) there are a bunch.

Comment: well i'll leave it here then.. now it has code. maybe it is a code issue =)

Comment: do teh urls in your link column have protocols?

Comment: yes they do. im stumped.